# In Corda, how can I query the vault for all states recorded after a specific state?

Tags: corda

I have the `StateRef` for a state that was recorded by my node. How can I get a stream of all the states recorded by my node since that `StateRef` was recorded?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do two things:

1. Identify when the `StateRef` you have was recorded
2. Start streaming updates from after that time

Here's an example RPC client that would do this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Getting an RPC connection to the node.
    require(args.size == 1) { "Usage: ExampleClientRPC <node address>" }
    val nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(args[0])
    val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)
    val rpcOps = client.start("user1", "test").proxy

    // Change this to an actual StateRef.
    val dummyStateRef = StateRef(SecureHash.zeroHash, 0)

    // Getting the time the state was recorded.
    val queryByStateRefCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = listOf(dummyStateRef))
    val queryByStateRefResults = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(queryByStateRefCriteria)
    val queryByStateRefMetadata = queryByStateRefResults.statesMetadata
    val dummyStateRefRecordedTime = queryByStateRefMetadata.single().recordedTime

    // Getting the states recorded after that time.
    val queryAfterTimeExpression = TimeCondition(
            RECORDED, BinaryComparison(BinaryComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, dummyStateRefRecordedTime))
    val queryAfterTimeCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(
            status = ALL,
            timeCondition = queryAfterTimeExpression)
    val queryAfterTimeResults = rpcOps.vaultTrackBy<ContractState>(queryAfterTimeCriteria)
    val afterTimeStates = queryAfterTimeResults.states
}
```